# IPv6, IPv4, UDP, and TCP all on one instance in Google Cloud

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ipv6, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

My Google cloud instance needs to support IPv4, IPv6, TCP, and UDP all on the same instance.

I've found [this article](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6) that shows how to get IPv4, IPv6, and TCP with a global network load balancer, but it does not include UDP.

My instance is on GCE right now, but I am likely going to move over to GKE in the near future, so I'm looking for a solution that works on both.

Comment: That is for a load balancer, but you mention a single virtual machine instance. Exactly what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Either via a load balancer or single instance is fine. I just need to find a way to get TCP and UDP traffic to my instance over both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: A Google load balancer can't do UDP, but you can certainly speak it directly from your instance, like any other host on the Internet. Keep in mind that [Google Cloud doesn't support IPv6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904387) on individual instances or VPCs. At this time only Amazon AWS meets all your requirements, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help, @MichaelHampton. That answers my question. It looks like AWS will support what I need, but not Google Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has added [IPv6 support to a limited subset of regions which would enable you to run a VM with a public IPv6 /96](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ipv6-addresses).

Note that Google APIs and services are not reachable via IPv6.

There's a write-up of how to set it up here:
[GCP, basic IPv6 set up for Linux VM Instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/1070632/gcp-basic-ipv6-set-up-for-linux-vm-instance)

If you have a Google Customer Rep, you should ask them about IPv6 and GKE.

If you want to use k8s in Google with IPv6 today, you'll probably want something like [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/getting_started/gce.md).

The only thing I know I need UDP+IPv6 for is DNS, and for that I'm willing to run a couple of VMs as opposed to a full k8s cluster.